# OData WebAPI Action's parameters deserialzation

Tags: .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, odata

try to use OData webAPI and call an action with a param, serialized into json without metainformation.
So, I want to pass an object of a type:

```
public class SomeRequest
{
    public RequestReason Reason { get; set; }
}

public enum RequestReason
{
    New,
    Dublicate
}
```

I've createed a mdel, configured an action:

```
var action = modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().Action("SomeRequest");
action.Parameter<SomeRequest>("Info");
action.Returns<HttpResponseMessage>();
var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
configuration.EnableOData(model);
```

Have code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage RequestIDCard(int key, [FromBody]ODataActionParameters param)
{
    object value;
    param.TryGetValue("Info", out value);
///!!!!
}
```

and expect to have value with real type SomeRequest, cast the type and process it...
Then I make a POST request with headers

> Content-Type: application/json;json=light; charset=utf-8 Accept:
>   application/json;odata=light

and body

> {"Info":{"Reason":1}}

But I get object of type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject" and sure it cannot be casted! 
But if I change object type to int, everything work :)
Is it a bug of WebAPI OData or I do something wrong?

Comment: Just a quick note: the "odata=light" portion of your content-type and accept headers is from a pre-released version of the new JSON specification and has since been removed. Instead, use just "application/json" or "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata"

Comment: The same result. I use latest version of all libs from Nuget, System.Web.Http.OData v0.3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things wrong with your usage,

1. Enums are mapped to string's in aspnet Web API OData. So, your request body should have { "Reason" : 'Duplicate' instead.
2. As Jen has already ppointed out, application/json;odata=light is not a supported media type. You might want to use 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata' or just 'application/json'.
3. action.Returns< HttpResponseMessage > is not useful. This would map HttpResponseMessage as a  complex type in the EDM model of your service. I am not sure what the mapping would look like. Generally, you want to expose types that from your models in the EDM model that you are building. You should choose a more specific type from your models, more like,

   action.Returns< IDCard >();

Comment: 1. No, they does not. I created a test action without parameters which returns  SomeRequest's instance(with fake data) in json format, and used it as a sample. And it returns enum as a number.
2. As I wrote in comments, with 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata' or 'application/json' I have the same result